# Как в C# реализовано создание string из строки в кавычках?

Tags: c#

Если я пишу в коде строку в двойных кавычках, она сразу становится безымянным экземпляром типа `string`, а значит я могу поставить в конце точку и использовать методы со строкой. Если поставлю символ в одинарных кавычках - это будет `char`. А как мне реализовать что-то подобное со своим классом? Ну например если я что то возьму в кавычки, перед которыми будет символ звездочка (или просто в звездочки), то чтобы создавался экземпляр класса `MyClass`?

Comment: То что вы хотите - это изменение синтаксиса; в C# не предусмотрено. Если всё же очень хочется, возьмите язык с макросами, позволяющий изменять синтаксис. Например, Nemerle - это язык для платформы .NET, он во многом похож на C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

То, что вы просите - это литералы для пользовательских типов. К сожалению, все поддерживаемые типы литералов жестко прописаны в стандарте языка.

Но вместо них (в какой-то мере) можно использовать implicit-операторы. Например:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator MyClass(string source)
    {
        var tokens = source.Split(':');
        return new MyClass
        {
            Prefix = tokens[0],
            Suffix = tokens[1]
        };
    }
}
```

позволяет создавать объекты класса как:

```
MyClass val = "a:b";

Console.WriteLine(val.Prefix); // a
Console.WriteLine(val.Suffix); // b
```

Answer (score 5):

Реально преобразовать строку в собственный класс Вы не можете, так же как и вводить свои синтаксические правила.

Собственный класс Вы можете создать только через конструктор. Остальных вариантов, допускаемых синтаксисом C# мне не известно.

Однако, если Вас всего лишь интересует создание некоторых дополнительных, методов-расширений, которые так же будут доступны через точку для строки, то можете создать статический класс и в нем реализовать необходимые методы:

```
public static class StringHelper {
    public static string TestMethod(this string str) {
        return "12345 " + str;
    }
}
```

А обращаться можете так:

```
class Program {
    static void Main() {            
        System.Console.Write("testStr".TestMethod());
    }   
}
```

Таким же способом Вы, кстати, можете и создать свой класс (но тут мне не ясно, чем такой вариант удобнее обычного конструктора), например:

```
public static class StringHelper {
    public static MyOwnClass AsMyOwnClass(this string str) {
        return new MyOwnClass(str);
    }
}
...
   var myVar = "Test Str".AsMyOwnClass();
```

Comment: Очень полезно. Однако, жаль, что нельзя осуществить мою задумку. Возможно ли через `StringHelper` поменять поведение `String`? То есть чтобы при определении нового экземпляра `String` происходили некоторые действия?

Comment: А можно как то в XAML использовать методы расширения для `string`? Тот же `TestMethod` из вашего примера.

Answer (score 0):

Никак, класс `String` - `sealed` класс.

Или лезть в дебри CLI, в исхоники, и пытаться сделать хак, что не совсем просто.